# php code to read from text file and compare the user input with the content

Tags: php, file, for-loop

i have a php code that read from text file an compare the user input with its content.

the problem is that the system read from the text file but doesn't compare

what is the error and is their another method?

## testfile.txt

test
admin
people
bob321
danyjd
ajb

## code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["Search"]))
{
    $data= file('testfile.txt');
    $accessData = array();
    foreach($data as $line){
        list($dataFile1) = explode(',', $line);

    }

    $dataInput = isset($_POST['name'])? $_POST['name']:'';

    if(array_key_exists($dataInput, $accessData)){
        echo "text exist";
    }
    else{
        echo "text doesn't exist";
    }
}
?>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
     <form action="test2.php" method="post">
          <p>enter your string <input type ="text"  id = "idName"  name="name" /></p>
          <p><input type ="Submit" name="Search" /></p>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$accessData` is an empty array...

Comment: `list($dataFile1)` shouldn't that be `list($accessData)`?

Comment: @chade_ i don't think so be cause the $dataFile1 is the variable that handle the compared string

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$accessData[]` instead of `list($dataFile1)`? Using [list](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) here feels redundent

Comment: @WillParky93 still does't compare correctly

Comment: @Dany7elo your issue is that `the system read from the text file but doesn't compare`. If `$accessData` is empty; `if(array_key_exists($dataInput, $accessData)){` will never be true. I can't find any other usage of `$dataFile1`

Comment: @WillParky93  why? in the if statement i am trying to compare between the user input and the content of the file ist wrong ?

Comment: @WillParky93 i removed the dataFile1 and make the accessData as an array in the for loop but still did not get the correct answer

Comment: Please show an example of `testfile.txt`, if your working on building some kind of authentication with this stop. ;p

Comment: What's the need for `list($dataFile1) = explode(',', $line);` in this if your file has no `,` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this, using [array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php), reducing the check to 1 line :/

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["Search"]) && !empty($_POST['name']))
{
    if (array_search($_POST['name'], file('testfile.txt')) !== false){
        echo "text exist";
    }
    else{
        echo "text doesn't exist";
    }
}
```